# Cant get listbox to show for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, what I am trying to do is open a file when pressing a button and displaying the contents in a listbox.  This is what I have so far, but I am not getting the listbox to display, let alone get the info to be in the listbox:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

import time
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

def listbox(listbox):

    def open_file():
            file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
            openFile = open(file)
            for line in openFile:
                 listbox.insert(END, line)

    open_file()


class App:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        frame = Frame(parent.title("Buttons"))
        frame.pack()
        root.pack_propagate(0)

        self.exit = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.exit.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.open = Button(frame, text="Open...", command=self.call_listbox)
        self.open.pack(side=LEFT)

        frame.listbox = Frame()
        scrollme = Scrollbar(frame.listbox)
        self.listbox = Listbox(frame.listbox, yscrollcommand = scrollme.set)
        scrollme.config(command = self.listbox.yview)
        scrollme.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        self.listbox.pack()
        self.listbox.insert(END, "Code:")

    def call_listbox(self):
        listbox(self.listbox)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

any suggestions?  thanks

Comment: Any reason why you've got `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` as the first line of your script? This looks like Python to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to pack the frame that contains the listbox.

FWIW, your overloading of the name "listbox" makes your code very confusing - you have `def listbox(listbox)`, `self.listbox` and `frame.listbox`. And you also have `call_listbox` and the `Listbox` class to add to the confusion.

Comment: I am packing right after scrollme.pack, and I do agree that it is confusing, this is just some rough coding and havent had a chance to label things the way I want to yet

Comment: @Blizbiggy: no, you are not. Nowhere in your code do you do something like `frame.listbox.pack()`.  Read my answer again: you aren't packing the _frame_ that the listbox is in.

Comment: ohhhhhhh  ok i see it now lol.  and it works after that :)  after staring at it for a while the functions seem to merge into one O.O  i suppose it is time to make them labeled a bit better now.  Thanks again!